# Error inflating class fragment with maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio

When I run my app, after click the option that directs to the activity maps, it ends with `Fatal Exception`.

```
luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
```

I am using the `API23` and has updated the calls of maps with `SupportMapFragment`.

**My activity_maps**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My build.gradle dependencies**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

**My MapsActivity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.i("InfoLocalizacao", Integer.toString(intent.getIntExtra("InfoLocalizacao", -1)));

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Then

```
GoogleMap map;// Global
 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: Add `FrameLayout` as Parent Layout

Comment: Why should you add fragment in xml ?I think you should getFragmentManger and add the fragment in Activity.Or add mapview instead of mapfragment in xml.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I made the changes according to their response edited but still return the same error.When insert the `map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`, I need to remove the condition with `getMapAsync` - `map.getMapAsync(this);`.